# Publishing Oracle SQL code results in centralized platform

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting

I am looking for a publishing platform that is compatible with Oracle to which I may easily report results from a given query. Ideally, the end user would only see the option to select a published report - the code would be invisible to them. I have explored connecting to Oracle via sharepoint with limited effectiveness. If anyone has documentation or if I need to elaborate further, please let me know.

The end game is such that I would like to CALL UPON Oracle from the end users platform and be able to run code and publish the report for their consumption.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oracle [Application Express](https://apex.oracle.com/en/) - Apex - is great for basic interactive web based reporting.

Comment: If you have Sharepoint you probably have access to MS Reporting Services. Easy to deploy (and have Sharepoint Integration).

Comment: An oracle sales person just finished heavily pushing Oracle Jet on us.

Comment: The most common one I've seen is Business Objects from SAP. back in the day we had a perl based webpage that had a drop down of reports and allowed input params and the perl code executed a generated report query... It was ugly but it worked like a charm.

Comment: Are you looking for a BI/Reporting tool?, or just want to output the results of your query?